# Why isn't my gmail or yahoo email accounts receiving mail when I use this PHP mail function

Tags: php, gmail, mime

The send_mail function with the headers.  What could be blocking this from being received. I know it works at least sometimes, my work email receives it just fine.

Another thing that might be of note:
- with a different ssl page the function did send correctly to gmail
- on this totally separate domain, it is not.

```
function send_mail($from,$fromName,$to,$object,$bodyText,$bodyHtml){
    $site = "mywebsite.ca";
    $from = $fromName." <".$from.">";
    $limite = "_----------=_parties_".md5(uniqid (rand()));

    $header  = "Reply-to: ".$from."\n";
    $header .= "From: ".$from."\n";
    $header .= "X-Sender: <".$site.">\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
    $header .= "X-auth-smtp-user: ".$from." \n";    
    $header .= "X-abuse-contact: ".$from." \n"; 
    $header .= "Date: ".date("D, j M Y G:i:s O")."\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$limite."\"";

    $message = "";
    $message .= "--".$limite."\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
    $message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $bodyText;

    $message .= "\n\n--".$limite."\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; ";
    $message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"; ";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\n\n";
    $message .= $bodyHtml;

    $message .= "\n--".$limite."--";
    if(mail($to, $object, $message, $header)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: may be mail was thrown to spam folder.Did you check spam folder?

Comment: nope, there's nothing in the spam folder

Comment: It's strange because I've used this before to send to gmail and it worked just fine, html included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(mail($to, $object, $message, $header)) return true;
    else return false;
```

heres the code that send the mail to your email try to debug it it all the variable inside specially the $to varible because its your email where the message will be send.

try this

```
if(mail($to,$object,$message,$header)){
      //echo all
}
else{
      //echo mssage not submit
}
```

Comment: this will distinguish if maill function definetly runs add send the messsage.

Comment: The function is working for my work email address, but not for gmail, or yahoo! for that matter

Comment: ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from); try to add.. for headers

Answer (score 0):

Why are you merging `Text`  and `HTML` content type in same variable ?

```
$message = "";
$message .= "--".$limite."\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
$message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $bodyText;

$message .= "\n\n--".$limite."\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; ";
$message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"; ";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\n\n";
$message .= $bodyHtml;
```

Use any one of them only

like instead of above

```
$message .= "\n\n--".$limite."\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; ";
$message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"; ";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\n\n";
$message .= $bodyHtml;
```

Comment: Actually `$bodyText` and `$bodyHtml` are different variables. And using both gives the recipient the option to display either plain text or html.

Comment: $bodytext and $bodyhtml are different but is one variable which has concatenation of $message html as well as text